# Do I need Dovecot on server if Gmail is hosting our email?

Tags: debian, dovecot, imap, gmail

I noticed a recurring error in the mail.log as well as when I run `service dovecot status` on a server I 'inherited' for my job (used for our production website). We have our MX records pointed to/email hosted by Gmail.

```
imap-login: Fatal: Couldn't parse private ssl_key: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line: Expecting PRIVATE KEY
```

When I checked the config file for dovecot, it looks like it was never configured. Before I begin addressing the issue here with the SSL and dovecot, I wonder if I should just disable it.

On a new test server, which I set up rather than inherited, I installed postfix for use with our Drupal-based website and a local CRM and all mail functions seem to be working just fine there without installing dovecot and the only difference in functionality between the test and prod servers is email, but I think not even that because mx records to gmail, so do I need to run dovecot on this server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dovecot is an IMAP and POP3 server. If you don't need to serve out email received locally then you don't need Dovecot.

Comment: Thank you. I understand from the documentation that Dovecot is an IMAP and POP3 server. I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something for server uses of that besides strictly delivering mail to local email clients like Outlook.